# Android: set Notification volume

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

Here I play a sound for every 30 sec using alarm manager and at I receive it in broadcast receiver  . I wanna customize default notification volume and need to set volume as per user changes . My snippet as follows

```
private void mynotification(Context context){
    final String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(ns);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.alarm/" +R.raw.tin),10);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1234, builder.build());

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the audio through the AudioManager

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#FLAG_SHOW_UI

I dont know what you exactly want to achieve, but you can get the current audio level and change it.

If I understand your question you should use setStreamVolume.

Comment: I don't wanna change current audio of device.. I just wanna change notification sound volume that by my app

Comment: I believe what you want to achieve is not possible, It's possible to change volume level per application in Android. But notification volume level is probably OS wide, and not application specific.